# jquery modal pop up in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I'm trying to replicate the example I see here 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated with the following asp.net mvc view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Partial";
}

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            $("#opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });
</script>

    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>

    <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>


    @section scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")

        }
```

but the jquery isn't firing, I'm not sure if I'm linking the jquery scripts right or what...

I've also tried this

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

on the top of the page but nothing

ultimately my goal is to use @Ajax.ActionLink (which is working for me) and then make the "div" that gets updated with the partial view into a modal popup. But for now, I can't get this modal working, I appreciate the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the quotes

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```